# How to install Android Wear Companion App on Android Phone Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I'm developing an android app which can push notifications to android wear device (watch in this case). I've no phone running Android 4.0.3 or above and 've no watch either. All I want to do is develop an app on emulator which can push notifications to watch on emulator.

I've followed and have created emulators with almost same specs as in this tutorial: https://kennethmascarenhas.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/developing-for-android-wear-with-emulators/

However, I'm stuck on step where it says: "Next, you will have to install the Android Wear companion app on your Phone emulator."

There's no google play app on the emulator. I've attempted to download couple of APK's from web (etc. http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-wear/android-wear-1-0-5-1630507-apk/), but it never installs. I can't figure this out. Kindly help.

Comment: "but it never installs" - can you be more specific here? How does the installation fail?

Comment: I renamed the apk to wearable.apk, placed it into platform-tools and issue this command on CMD an hour ago:

E:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install "E:\Program File
s\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\wearable.apk"

and still waiting. Nothing happens.

Comment: Although it doesn't solve your original issue, this particular one may be solved if you go to the settings (in your Android running in emulator), into the developer settings and enable USB debugging; that should allow the installation of apps through adb.

Comment: Alright. I did that. Enabled Debugging Options and then restarted the emulator. Still the app didn't install. I issued the same command as above but nothing happens.